# Excess demand function - general equilibrium

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Considering a pure exchange economy consisting of two consumers and goods. Consumer 1 has utility function$$
u(x,y) = 10 x^{0.6} + 5 y^{0.5}
$$
and the endowment vector $w_1 = (1,2)$. Consumer 2 has the utility function$$
u(x,y) = x^{0.4} · y^{0.6}
$$
with the endowment vector $w_2 = (2,1)$. How to write the excess demand function for this economy?

*My main question is solving the Lagrange function for Consumer 1.

Comment: What is your Lagrange function for Consumer 1?

Comment: $$
L = 10 x^{0.6} + 5 y^{0.5} - λ(Px.X + Py.Y - Px - 2Py)
$$

Comment: There is no need to take the logarithm. Just calculalate the partial derivatives w.r.t $X$ and $Y$ and set them equal to $0$. I would denote the the variables with the subscript 1. :$L = 10 X_1^{0.6} + 5 Y_1^{0.5} - λ(P_x\cdot X_1 + P_y\cdot Y_1 - P_x- 2P_y)$

Comment: problem is when I get the partial and solve for the x or y, they are not in terms of P only. I still have the other variable in there. and I cannot substitute it back to the constraint.(those decimals make it complicated).

Comment: You have to show at which step the problems occour. If I´m right after some steps there is an equation like $2.4X_1Y_1^{0.5}-Y_1^{0.5}=2X_1^{0.4}-X_1^{0.4}Y_1$. This can be solved for $Y_1$ by substitution.

Comment: $$
 L_{x} = 6x^{-0.4} - \lambda P_{1} = 0
$$

$$
L_{y} = 0.25y^{-0.5} - \lambda P_{2} = 0
$$

then I solve for Y and I get the following:

$$
y^{0.5} = \frac{25x^{0.4}P1}{6P2}
$$

but I want y, so I square it and put it in the constraint and get this:

$$
P_{1}X+\frac{25^{2}x^{0.8}P_{1}^{2}}{36P_{2}} = P_{1} + 2P_{2}
$$

but now how do I solve for x ?

Comment: OK. But first we should compare the intermediate results. Isn´t $L_y=2.5y^{-0.5}-\lambda P_2=0$?

Comment: yes you are right. it should be 2.5

Comment: but it does not change the big picture.

Comment: Just wait a minute.

Comment: You´re right the equation can not solved algebraically. Thus you have to apply an approximation method like the newton raphson method. But you need some values for the prices.

Comment: is there any other way? this question came up on an exam so I think there should be a way to solve it. can we do a sort of change of variable or something?

Comment: Maybe. As far as I tried I found nothing that really helps. But maybe the substitution $z^{0.5}=x^{0.6}$ might help.